# error 'moment' is not defined no-undef in ember.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, ember.js

I'm creating an application, a clock with timezone, it happens that it gives this error and I can not fix it, I'm also an initiator and I do not have much experience, the home page appears where the chosen clock is, but the page where the time zone would be It's blank, I'm waiting for help, thank you!

- ember-cli: 2.13.1
- node: 6.0.0
- os: linux x64

`Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
'instrument' is imported from external module 'ember-data/-debug' but 
never used

```
app/controllers/clock.js
14:36  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef
18:27  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef
25:15  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)


app/controllers/timezones.js
7:23  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef
9:19  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef
10:21  error  'moment' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)


Build successful (4919ms) – Serving on http://localhost:4200/



Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (17)                                    | 1460ms (85 ms)      
Rollup (1)                                    | 1214ms              
EslintValidationFilter (2)                    | 835ms (417 ms)      
Concat (8)                                    | 585ms (73 ms)       
TreeMerger (allTrees) (1)                     | 312ms`
```

**app/controllers/timezones.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
/* create array of timezones with name & offset */
init: function() {
    var timezones = [];
    for (var i in moment.tz._zones) {
      timezones.push({
        name: moment.tz._zones[i].name,
        offset: moment.tz._zones[i].offsets[0]
      });
    }
    this.set('timezones', timezones);
    this._super();
  },
  selectedTimezone: null,
  actions: {
    /* save a timezone record to our offline datastore */
    add: function() {
      var timezone = this.store.createRecord('timezone', {
        name: this.get('selectedTimezone').name,
        offset: this.get('selectedTimezone').offset
      });
      timezone.save();
    },        
    /* delete a timezone record from our offline datastore */
    remove: function(timezone) {
      timezone.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

**app/controllers/clock.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
init: function() {
    // Update the time.
    this.updateTime();
},

updateTime: function() {
    var _this = this;

    // Update the time every second.
    Ember.run.later(function() {
        _this.set('localTime', moment().format('h:mm:ss a'));

        _this.get('model').forEach(function(model) {
            model.set('time',
                      moment().tz(model.get('name')).format('h:mm:ss 
a'));
        });

        _this.updateTime();
    }, 1000);
},

localTime: moment().format('h:mm:ss a')
});
```

**app/model/timezone.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
offset: DS.attr('number')
});
```

**app/routes/clock.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('timezone');
}
});
```

**app/routes/timezones.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('timezone');
}
});
```

If you need any more files just talk

Comment: how are you importing moment?

Comment: It sounds like you are importing moment through bower, which adds a `moment` global variable to your project. The project is that the linter does not know this variable exists, so you have to [tell it it exists](http://jshint.com/docs/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get those errors, because you use a global ES Lint is not aware of. As @locks said in the comments, you need to [add](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) `moment`as a global to the ES Lint config:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "moment": true
  }
}
```

Or you can specify the global in your files as a comment:

**app/controllers/clock.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
/* global moment */

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  //your code
});
```

---

If you would happen to use either [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) or [ember-cli-moment-shim](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim), you could just import the moment global:

**app/controllers/clock.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  //your code
});
```

Comment: `/* globals moment */` instead of `/* moment */`

Comment: @kumkanillam: Ah thx! N.B. it is `/* global moment */` without the `s` :P.

Comment: Maybe it is a difference between ESLint and JSHint. See also http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals. As recent Ember CLI does use ESLint, I used their docs...

Comment: eslint is added in blueprint in ember-cli 2.14.0 but the OP's cli version is `2.13.1` so for OP jsHint might help. but for the future eslint is good. May be you can add both in your answer